# Can somebody give me recommendations to connect a wix blog with a next.js website?

Tags: next.js, blogs, velo

I am creating a website with next.js for a friend, she has a blog in Wix and she wants the website to have a integrated blog. Is better to create a blog from sracth with next js or try to connect her blog to the next.js website? I feel creating a blog from scrath it will take me lot of time and I have never done it. I have checked if there is a way of connecting wix website but can't find a clear answer. I have found that creating a blog using Hyvor blog you can do that easier, has anyone heard about it? Also wordpress has an option to connect the blog with a next,js website, but this two options means she needs to create a totaly new blog form scratch. What is the best option? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integrating Wix Blog:** While Wix offers a blogging platform, integrating it with a Next.js website might not be straightforward. Wix provides limited access to the underlying code and APIs, making it challenging to integrate seamlessly with a custom-built website. You might need to use Wix's embed options or APIs (if available) to display blog content on the Next.js site, but this approach may have limitations in terms of customization and flexibility.

**MY OPINION AS A WEB APP DEVELOPER -(especially react & next)**
if you not familiar with next.js and if you dont have time to learn and develop it go with other website builder like **wordpress** and connect it to next.js.

But if you don't want to limited controls, non up-scalable blog website you will definitely consider next.js, it will thrills you and its **SEO feature** is world class.